# Big-O notation of a method that calls a method of O(n)

Tags: java, time, big-o

```
public boolean equal(MyLinkedList a, MyLinkedList b) {
    String instanceA = encode(a);
    String instanceB = encode(b);
    return instanceA.equals(instanceB);
}
```

I was working on a project and looked at my code and realized I didn't know the time complexity rules of calling methods.

What would be the big-O notation of my equal method if the encode(String value) is of O(n)? Would it take into consideration the big-o notation of O(n) or would it be a simple O(1)?

Comment: Yes, you must take the method's time-complexity into consideration. Otherwise you would be able to make any algorithm to O(1) by using a helper function.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Simple answer, but thank you! I've always gotten that hunch, but thanks for confirming

Answer (score 2):

It would be O(n) in the worst case. If you think about it, it boils down to estimating the time complexity of testing for equality, the encodings do not add additional complexity to the problem.

The complexity of verifying that two strings are equal is most of the times < O(n). For example, the `equals` method could simply compare the length of the strings before actually comparing the contents of the strings, which has constant complexity. If the strings are of equal length, then the `equals` method could traverse the whole strings, thus O(n).

In CS stackexchange, the subject is discussed in more detail. Check it out here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127899/what-is-the-expected-time-complexity-of-checking-equality-of-two-arbitrary-strin

Comment: I feel like you've glossed over part of the question.

I would phrase it like so (but I have not edited your question so we can discuss this).

"It would be O(n) in the worst case. The Big O notation of your `equal`s method must take the complexity of all sub-functions into consideration otherwise it's not actually covering all of its complexity. If `encode` was `O(n!)`, then your `equal`s method would be `O(n!)`. However, under the assumption that the `encode` functions are `O(n)`, they will not add any additional complexity to the problem as `O(3n)` is `O(n)`."

Comment: Now I've understood better your question. The equality check is linear regarding the input size. i.e. O(n) with n the size of the input.
The inputs of the equals are a result of other operations in this case, which have complexity O(n). So, the resulting complexity will correspond to O(n) and you might be tempted to say that equals has complexity O(1). Consider the case where the encoding has complexity O(1), then the equals will not have complexity O(1) but O(n) with n the size of the original input. To calculate complexity "the biggest always wins" (pardon for this simplification).